# Returning from Function changes context to NULL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have three classes relevant to this issue. I'm implementing a hardware service for an application. PAPI (Platform API) is a hardware service class that keeps track of various hardware interfaces. I have implemented an abstract HardwareInterface class, and a class that derives it called HardwareWinUSB.

Below are examples similar to what I've done. I've left out members that don't appear to be relevant to this issue, like functions to open the USB connection:

```
class PAPI {
    HardwareInterface *m_pHardware;

    PAPI() {
        m_pHardware = new HardwareWinUSB();
    }

    ~PAPI() {
        delete m_pHardware;
    }

    ERROR_CODE WritePacket(void* WriteBuf)
    {
        return m_pHardware->write( WriteBuf);
    }
};

class HardwareInterface {
    virtual ERROR_CODE write( void* WriteBuf) = 0;
};

class HardwareWinUSB : public HardwareInterface
{
    ERROR_CODE write( void* Params)
    {
        // Some USB writing code.
        // This had worked just fine before attempting to refactor
        // Into this more sustainable hardware management scheme
    {
};
```

I've been wrestling with this for several hours now. It's a strange, reproducible issue, but is sometimes intermittent. If I step through the debugger at a higher context, things execute well. If I don't dig deep enough, I'm met with an error that reads

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in <ProjectName.exe>: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000
```

If I dig down into the PAPI code, I see bizarre behavior.
When I set a breakpoint in the body of WritePacket, everything appears normal. Then I do a "step over" in the debugger. After the return from the function call, my reference to 'this' is set to 0x00000000.

What is going on? It looks like a null value was pushed on the return stack? Has anyone seen something like this happen before? Am I using virtual methods incorrectly?

**edit**
After further dissection, I found that I was reading before calling write, and the buffer that I was reading into was declared in local scope. When new reads came in, they were being pushed into the stack, corrupting it. The next function called, write, would return to a destroyed stack.

Comment: What's going on is a bug in your code, somewhere. The results of a common, garden-variety bug is "undefined behavior", of which your observable results certainly qualify. You'll just have to figure out what your bug is. There is no paint-by-numbers recipe for figuring out and tracking down the bug, unfortunately. If there were, I'd be out of a job...

Comment: Thank you for your response, Sam. I do understand that this is a bug. I've been working professionally in C++ for about three years, and have yet to see an issue where the return stack gets corrupted like this. I was hoping for a hint from someone with more experience than myself, rather than "your problem is that you have a problem."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further dissection, I found that I was reading before calling write, and the buffer that I was reading into was declared in local scope (in the read function).

When new reads came in, they were being pushed into the stack, corrupting it. The next function I called, write, would return to a destroyed stack.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here. If possible, please also mark your reply as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

A buffer overrun can trash the return address on the stack.  You seem to be reading and writing packets with void pointers and without passing around explicit sizes, so a simple overrun bug seems quite likely.  The Visual Studio compiler has options to add stack integrity checks to detect these kinds of bugs, but they're not 100% perfect.  Nonetheless, make sure you have them switched on.

Also note that the Visual Studio debugger can occasionally (but rarely) show the wrong value for `this`, especially if you're trying to debug optimized code.  If you're at the `}` at the end of a method, I wouldn't necessarily worry about the debugger showing a bizarre value for `this`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Adrian. I had the same thought, that this could be cause by buffer overrun. So I tested this hypothesis. To do this, I replaced my void* parameters with uint8_t (&Buffer)[PACKET_SIZE], where PACKET_SIZE is a defined constant. This forced my code to always pass buffers of a particular size. This didn't seem to change anything, unfortunately. I looked at the points where I copy and set memory, and they look good to me. Are there any other reasons you think I could be seeing this?